# Calling native function from TypeScript in react-native

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

Lately I needed a simple function to interact with the native code, but I decided not to build a package, because it wouldn't be very useful. I created the java files exactly as if they were from a plugin and registered it in MainApplication.

I'm using typescript so now I'm struggling with the rn to java interaction. I tried with a js file as follows:

```
import NativeModules from 'react-native';
const AndroidService = NativeModules;
export default { AndroidService }
```

But then I have to define types (message from vs code):

```
Property 'play' does not exist on type '{ AndroidService: typeof import("/home/karol/Git/TailosiveHub-react/node_modules/@types/react-native/index"); }'.
```

I tried creating a `index.d.ts` file in the root of the project, but that doesn't work.

How do I define types for a native module in typescript?

MainApplication:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
    // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
    // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
    packages.add(new AndroidServicePackage());
    // packages.add(new MainReactPackage());
    return packages;
}
```

AndroidServicePackage:

```
@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
  return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(new AndroidServiceModule(reactContext));
}
```

AndroidServiceModule:

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "AndroidService";
}
```

Method:

```
@ReactMethod
public void play(String streamingURL/*, ReadableMap options*/) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by fixing my imports in the plugin ts file.
It now looks like this:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const AndroidService = NativeModules.AndroidService;
export default AndroidService;
```

Answer (score 2):

The NativeModules import contains the native modules inside, so you simply need to extract the AndroidService module as a property.

```
import NativeModules from 'react-native';
const { AndroidService } = NativeModules
export default { AndroidService }
```

Alternatively, you can simply export it like so:

```
import NativeModules from 'react-native';
exports.default = NativeModules.AndroidService;
```

This should give you the result that you want, provided that you have the corresponding native module named AndroidService added inside a package given to React Native.

Taken from [React Native's documentation on Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android)

Comment: This doesn't work: `AndroidService.default.play(url) is not a function (is undefined)`. I've added some more details to my post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add brackets around your assignation to `AndroidService` like so (that's called destructuring):

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'; 
export const { AndroidService } = NativeModules
```

Then in another file you can use it like so:

```js
import { AndroidService } from 'path/to/exporting/file';

...

AndroidService.play("YOUR_URL");
```

Comment: In the file where I import the module vs code tells me `Property 'AndroidService' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/karol/Git/TailosiveHub-react/node_modules/@types/react-native/index")'`
And if I run the app I get: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_AndroidService.AndroidService.play')`